# Reshape weird month/day dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I would like to import a txt file with the following structure into a dataframe in R:

```
Year 1 
Day  Jan  Feb Mar ... Dec
1
2
3`
..
31
```

However, the weird structure of the data (months in the columns, from column 2 to column 13, and days from 1 to 31 in the rows) render it challenging. I would like to get a dataframe with a date variable (dd-mm) and a value variable

Comment: It is not clear about the question.  What is the expected output

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file, like whatever it is that you're having trouble reading in? Otherwise, it's difficult to diagnose formatting problems

Comment: See pasted sample here: https://pastebin.com/0Ncv1pXR. I would like to get a dataframe with a date variable (dd-mm) and a value variable.

Comment: Sorry about it. See updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a tab separated document. However there are some extra columns added when parsed. `readr` is a package that'll help you parse it. Also, I think you want to convert from wide format to long format. If that is the case, then `tidyr` is your friend here

```
data <- read_tsv('      Nov     Dec     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     

1       -       -       -       442.328     -       -       675.653     652.236     512.411     462.336     431.440     373.112     
2       -       -       -       437.207     -       -       659.082     649.690     512.661     459.944     431.440     373.326     
3       -       -       -       432.130     -       -       663.897     642.369     513.164     458.285     426.627     373.326     
4       -       -       -       429.144     -       -       665.892     640.122     518.193     454.500     423.660     373.326     
5       -       -       -       428.235     -       -       665.892     640.122     518.697     454.028     420.931     373.540     
6       -       -       -       448.891     -       -       666.749     641.806     518.697     450.264     418.437     375.681     
7       -       -       -       481.933     -       -       664.176     643.210     513.726     448.385     418.210     375.467') %>%
  select(-X2, -X15) %>%
  rename(day = X1) 

data %>%
  gather(key = month, value = value, -day)
```